# Как алгоритм использовать для решения задачи?

Tags: python

не могу понять как решить следующую задачу:

На вход программа получает две строки. В первой находится список целых чисел, разделенных пробелом. Во второй строке программа получает натуральное число group_size. Программа должна определить, можно ли полученный список разделить на группы размера group_size так, чтобы в каждой группе все элементы были одинаковы. На выходе программа должна вывести True или False.
Пример входных данных:
0 6 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 5 2 5 5 0 1 3 1 7 7 6 2 1 2 5 0 0 1 6 6
2
Выходные данные:
False

Вот я начал так решать:

```
string='3 2 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4'
lst=string.split()
lst.sort(reverse=False) #1122223333334444
print(lst)
group=int(2)
print(group)
ind=0
lstgr=[]
#print(type(lstgr))
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i]=int(item) #11 22 22 33 33 33 44 44
    for j in range(0,group):
        lstgr.append(lst[i])
    #print(i,lst[i],ind)
```

отсортировал список, но не понимаю, как можно разделить на необходимые группы и сравнить их? можете подсказать?

Comment: а можете объяснить что за строка? просто не совсем понимаю что означает тут процент

Comment: остаток от деления знаю. но не понимаю, что означает длинное условие, да еще с процентом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать так:

```
string = '0 6 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 5 2 5 5 0 1 3 1 7 7 6 2 1 2 5 0 0 1 6 6 2' # входная строка
group_size = 2 # по сколько группируем

numbers = string.split() # преобразуем в список

for num in set(numbers):
    c = numbers.count(num) # сколько раз число встречается в списке
    if c%group_size: # если кол-во появлений в списке не кратно размеру группы - задача невыполнима
        print(False)
        break
else:
    # сюда программа доходит, если проверила все числа и все прошли проверку кол-ва вхождений
    print(True)
```

Comment: Квадратичный алгоритм. :( Можно сделать за линию.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не знаю способа, но было бы интересно взглянуть. Ваш ответ видел, он не является линейным, судя по замерам времени (время выполнения моей и вашей функции почти одинаково на случайных данных разных объемов с различным параметром размеры группы), к тому же требует больше памяти.

Comment: На случайных данных ваша программа рано выходит из цикла.

Comment: Сделал тесты. `sort-count`: 5000 пар - 0.5s, 10000 - 2s, 20000 - 7.6s, 40000 - 31s. `counter`: 100000 пар - 0.2s, 200000 - 0.3s, 400000 - 0.7s, 800000 - 1.2s, 1600000 - 2.4s.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy интересно. Вы к тоже дали понять, что сортировка в моем коде излишня...

Comment: Сейчас она лишняя. Можно сделать полезной: `sorted` -> `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: `map(int` не нужен. Какая разница что сортировать/сравнивать/группировать - числа или строки? Реальный порядок нам не важен, важна только одинаковость элементов.

Answer (score 0):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) считает одинаковые элементы. После проверяется что все счётчики делятся на размер группы:

```
import collections


c = collections.Counter(input().split())
size = int(input())
print(all(s % size == 0 for s in c.values()))
```

> ```
> $ echo -e "3 2 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 3 2 1 3 4 2 4\n2" | python groups.py
> True
> $ echo -e "0 6 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 5 2 5 5 0 1 3 1 7 7 6 2 1 2 5 0 0 1 6 6\n2" | python groups.py
> False
> ```